# Optimizing a MySQL query (Update + subquery)

Tags: sql, mysql

I want to change the values of column **this** in **table_one** where **this** = 1 and **id** value of that row exists anywhere in **table_two**'s column **other_id**

So I'm using this query:

```
UPDATE table_one SET this='0' WHERE this='1' AND table_one.id IN (SELECT other_id FROM table_two);
```

The query took several hours without yet finishing, so I was wondering if there is a way to accomplish it faster.

Both **table_one.id** and **table_two.other_id** have unique values if that matters.

**table_one** has 550k rows

**table_two** has 30k rows

MySQL 5.0.22

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually the solution was to add indexes for both table_one.id and table_two.other_id.
I mentioned they're unique, but I didn't mean that they have indexes, so my bad for not clarifying that.

After adding the indexes the query took less than a minute.

Also replacing IN with EXISTS gave me a syntax error, so I stuck with IN.

Answer (score 1):

try using EXISTS instead of IN

Answer (score 1):

An `UPDATE...JOIN` is an alternative to the `EXISTS` answer provided by *tuffkid* and *Brian Hooper*.  I've tested both, and they both take the same time (2.52 seconds on my computer):

```
UPDATE table_one
JOIN table_two
  ON table_one.id = table_two.other_id
SET this=0
  WHERE table_one.this=1;
```

The joined columns should be indexed, and if `table_two.other_id` has a `UNIQUE` index, the query should run very fast.

**Example**

Create tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_one` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `this` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `this` (`this`)
);

CREATE TABLE `table_two` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `other_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `other_id` (`other_id`)
);
```

Insert some test data:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS populate//
CREATE PROCEDURE populate()
BEGIN
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
    WHILE i < 550000 DO
        INSERT INTO table_one (this) VALUES ((i MOD 18)+1);
        IF i MOD 18 = 0 THEN
            INSERT INTO table_two (other_id) VALUES (i+1);
        END IF;
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;
END;
//
DELIMITER ;

CALL populate();
```

Run the update:

```
UPDATE table_one
JOIN table_two
  ON table_one.id = table_two.other_id
SET this=0
  WHERE table_one.this=1;

Query OK, 30556 rows affected (2.52 sec)
Rows matched: 30556  Changed: 30556  Warnings: 0

UPDATE table_one
  SET this=0
  WHERE this=1 AND
    EXISTS (SELECT other_id
      FROM table_two
      WHERE other_id = table_one.id);

Query OK, 30556 rows affected (2.52 sec)
Rows matched: 30556  Changed: 30556  Warnings: 0
```

Comment: This is fantastic; the JOIN syntax is exactly what I was looking for – it's quick and it's elegant. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To expand upon tuffkid's answer...

```
UPDATE table_one
    SET this='0'
    WHERE this='1' AND
          EXISTS (SELECT other_id
                      FROM table_two
                      WHERE other_id = table_one.id);
```